# stripe NodeJS not returning a response

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I have a stripe account, I'm trying to set up stripe connect with test custom accounts using node.js. no matter what I do, every time I try to access stripe in any way in the code, it doesn't send a response. No errors, no accounts, just no response at all. I've tried using the secret key, I've tried using the public key. I don't see any requests in the stripe dashboard either. Thanks in advance!

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('API_KEY')
const registerStripe = async () => {
        console.log('getting account')
        const account = await stripe.accounts.create({
           country: 'US',
           type: 'custom',
           requested_capabilities: ['card_payments', 'transfers'],
        }, function(err, account) {
           console.log(err);
           console.log(account);
        });
        console.log(account)
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you're starting the process with `await registerStripe()` just afterwards, is that correct?

Comment: Well it's a button that calls the function, no await

Comment: same things happen when I do await registerStripe()

Comment: And no error messages or nothing from the console while running in Node?

Comment: Nope, literally nothing, no error no account info, just says getting account and that's it

Comment: Thinking I'll try making a different stripe project and using those API keys, maybe somehow this one got messed up

Comment: I've also tried using express accounts instead, which I've decided to use. Still no luck, when I run stripe.oauth.token I get no response, I tried putting it in a try catch statement, no error, just nothing.

Comment: Just did a setup myself pretty quickly. What version of node are you using? Commands I ran: `yarn init -y; yarn add stripe; echo "const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_KEY');\n(async () => {\nstripe.customers.create({\nemail: 'customer@example.com',\n})\n.then(customer => console.log(customer.id))\n.catch(error => console.error(error));\n})();\n" > test.js;` then `node test.js`.

Comment: In the `./node_modules/stripe/package.json` it says it requires `"node": "^8.1 || >=10.*"`

Comment: using node v13.8.0, tried to run the code you shared and still no response

Comment: btw I tested with curl and that did work

Comment: what if you just `console.log(stripe)` and `console.log(stripe.customers)` to see if the object and function exists.

Comment: object/function both exist

Comment: so I ran the exact code you posted and it works, only problem is it doesn't work when it's inside the react app.

Comment: if I run node test.js within the project I get the response, but if I export and call the function in App.js I get no response

Comment: Can you post the code you have for React. Just a sidenote, I don't think you're meant to put this code on the frontend, because it would expose the secret key to the public. You would probably do a React request to your NodeJS API which has the code I put above.

Comment: Yep, I realized this so I ended up making a node server to handle all things stripe, would've done it with firebase cloud functions but you have to upgrade the project in order to speak to outside servers from firebase.

Comment: Oh yeah, I remember that paywall feature with firebase. But you manage to get it working?

Comment: Yep all working fine! Thanks a ton for the help, without you I definitely wouldn't have figured it out!

Comment: I'll post my own answer with the details of what I did in a bit.